# How do I resolve JWT Validator Error in Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt

I'm trying to create an access token using JWT in ExpressJS but it shows an error: `TypeError: validator.isValid is not a function`. I know the error is coming from the JWT
method for signing a payload using the SSH public key but I can't seem to pinpoint why and fix it.

Below are the related program app (Without the middleware because it's not related to the error):

*Server root (app):*

```
import express from "express";
import routes from "./routes";
import config  from "config";
import connect from "./utils/connect";
import logger from "./utils/logger";
import { json } from "body-parser";

const port = config.get<number>("port");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(1337, async () => { 
    logger.info(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
    
    // DB connection
    connect();

    // URL Rotues
    routes(app);
})
```

*Routes:*

```
import { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import { createUserSessionHandler } from "./controllers/session.controller";
import { createUserHandler } from "./controllers/user.controller";
import validateResource from "./middleware/validateResource";
import { createSessionSchema } from "./schema/session.schema";
import { createUserSchema } from "./schema/user.schema";

export default function routes(app: Express) {
  app.post("/api/sessions", validateResource(createSessionSchema), createUserSessionHandler);
}
```

*Session service:*

```
import SessionModel from "../models/session.model";
import log from "../utils/logger";

export async function createSession (userId: string, userAgent: string) {
    try {
        const session = await SessionModel.create({user: userId, userAgent});
        return session.toJSON();
    } catch (e: any) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

*Token util:*

```
import config from "config";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const privateKey = config.get<string>("privateKey");
const publicKey = config.get<string>("publicKey");

export function createJWT(
  object: Object,
  option?: jwt.SignOptions | undefined
) {
  return jwt.sign(object, privateKey);
}

export function verifyJWT(token: string) {
  try {
    const verifiedToken = jwt.verify(token, publicKey);

    return {
      tokenIsValid: false,
      expired: false,
      verifiedToken,
    };
  } catch (e: any) {
    return {
      tokenIsValid: false,
      expired: (e.message = "JWT expired"),
      verifiedToken: null,
    };
  }
}
```

*Session controller:*

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { userDocument } from "../models/user.model";
import { createSession } from "../service/session.service";
import { validatePassword } from "../service/user.service";
import { createJWT } from "../utils/jwtToken";
import config from "config";

export async function createUserSessionHandler(req: Request, res: Response) {

  // Validate user's password
  const user = await validatePassword(req.body.email, req.body.password);

  if (!user) res.status(401).send("Invalid email or password");

  // Create a session
  if (user) {
    const session = await createSession(user._id, req.get("user-agent") || "");

    // create an access token
    const accessToken = createJWT(
      {
        ...user,
        session: session._id
      },
      { expiresIn: config.get<string>("accessTokenTtl") }
    );

    // create a refresh token
    const refreshToken = createJWT(
        {
          ...user,
          session: session._id
        },
        { expiresIn: config.get<string>("accessTokenTtl") }
    );

    // Return access and refresh token
    return res.status(200).send({accessToken, refreshToken});
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ever solve this? im having the same issue, are you following Tom's RESTful api tutorial ? cuz the code looks pretty similar. Having the exact same issue you describe

Comment: @xunux Yes, I did. It has nothing to do with the JWT package but instead with how SSH key strings (public and private keys) are formatted. Make sure there are no white spaces in the key.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I also figured it out after trying different algorithms and different keys. There were a couple other nuances, even removing all whitespace sometimes didnt work depending on the level of encryption of the keys and the algorithm used